# Handle Ownership

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

This issue has been bothering me for quite a time now about how can I handle the ownership.

Lets say I am building a project management application. So I will have multiple users who will be creating multiple projects.

lets say a user with `user_id = 1` creates projects with `project_id = 1009` and `project_id = 2349` .

And another user `user_id = 21` creates projects `project_id=35` and `project_id = 44` .

So after the user ( `user_id = 1` ) logs in to the website, he/she should only be able to access  the projects with id `1009` and `2349` and projects `35` and `44` should be only accessible to `user_id = 21`.

So when `example.com/project?id=1009` is viewed by `user_id=21` and since he/she did not created the project, they should not be able to view / access it.

is checking this way the only way to properly handle the ownership?

`if($project->user_id == $session_user_id){
      // can access it 
}else{
     // Cannot access it 
}`

Comment: Can you be more specific as to what your question is?  And, I'm sure you are going to want more than a one-to-one relationship between users and projects at some point.

Answer (score 1):

Create in your database user_project_acl table and keep

user project
1  |   1009
1  |   2349

and load only necessary projects and you never need to have if statment